# How to access Bin\debug folder path from installer file?

Tags: c#-4.0

I created one C# windows application. In the application I put Reports and Scripts folder on Bin\Debug folder. The reports folder accessed from bin\debug folder dynamically. I created one Visual studio setup project. Then added the C# project output to that setup project.

Now how to access the bin folder from setup project? May I add bin folder here or any alternative suggestions?

[image]